# PHP Webdriver - Get Firefox PID in Linux / Windows

Tags: php, bash, selenium, centos, php-webdriver

Good morning all,

PHP Webdriver (Facebook) - Is there any way I can get the PID (Linux, Centos 7) of the currently lunched browser (Firefox) during the session?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's as simple as `pidof firefox`.

Comment: The problem is that there are many co-current test executions, I'd like to catch the PIDs of the executed Firefox instances, so I could terminate those that are stuck for more then specific amount of minutes

Answer (score 0):

`ps` command takes a lot of input arguments. With `--format` and `--sort` you can find the processes with their durations and sort them by the duration.

```
ps -ef --format=pid,cmd,time --sort=time | grep firefox
```

You can filter this out further and develop a script to kill the `firefox` processes with the duration higher than a given value.